# Screen crash for Ubuntu 16.04 (sorry for bad title)

Tags: ubuntu, crash

I was working on my Toshiba VG10S laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 . The screen went crazy like below:

[image: IMG:]

I don't know what caused it, I restarted my system and it was normal back again.

But surely, I don't want it to happen again.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I constantly encounter this on old computers. The problem is driver compatibility. Check if you have recently updated the kernel or video drivers. As a rule, this is still accompanied by a complete system freeze.  I recommend that you be more careful with updates.